# Angular 2- Select sets dynamic template but the option is always the first one

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, typescript, angular, conditional-statements

I am working on a project for traineeship, i need to build a system for the new CMS. I am new in Angular 2 and Typescript, I hope you guys can help me out.

I am trying to create a dynamic template loader which did succeed but the select option is not "update". I best show you my code so you can sketch an image of it.

THIS IS THE TEMPLATE:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" *ngFor="#condition of conditions;#conditionindex = index">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <select class="form-control" (change)="onChange(conditionindex, $event.target.value)">
            <option *ngFor="#c of catalog;#catalogindex = index" [value]="catalogindex">{{c.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <condition-detail [condition]="condition"></condition-detail>
</div>

<a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="newCondition()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click)="deleteCondition()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i></a>
```

THIS IS THE COMPONENT:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'condition-builder',
    templateUrl: 'app/conditionbuilder.component.html',
    providers: [ConditionService],
    directives: [ConditionDetailComponent]
})

export class ConditionBuilderComponent implements OnInit {
    //public selectedCondition: string;
    conditions: Condition[] = [];
    catalog: Condition[] = [];

constructor(private _conditionService: ConditionService) { }

getConditions() {
    this._conditionService.getConditions().then(conditions => this.catalog = conditions);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getConditions();
}

onChange(conditionsIndex, catalogIndex) {
    //console.log(this.selectedCondition);
    console.log(conditionsIndex);
    console.log(catalogIndex);
    this.conditions[conditionsIndex] = this.catalog[catalogIndex];
}

newCondition() {
    this.conditions.push(this.catalog[0]);
}

deleteCondition() {
    this.conditions.pop();
}
```

}

So whats going on here? It updates the template but its select option will not change with it. So its given DateCondition in my case and after that I select StringCondition. The template changes to StringCondition but its select option will remain DateCondition it only change after two clicks.

I also put every file in plunker to create a better view for you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/WRSbdQkla3uQlW3HLxQd?p=preview

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/92z2oe7f4w5x2b5/conditions.jpg?dl=0

Here in the link i show you how it works, the second one is selected as StringCondition as the template shows but it the first select will stay DateCondition.